# Data generator for a given flow type

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, flowtype, data-generation

We use [flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/) in our frontend project (on react), so all the types are defined i.e.:

```
type TUser = {
   firstName: string,
   lastName: string,
   age: number,
   birthdate: Date
}
```

So every time any type is changed I need to fix unit tests, which is annoying a bit. Maybe there is a npm package or library which can generate fake data for a given flow type?

I.e. something like this:

```
const user = generateDataForType(TUser);
```

If not, maybe [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) have something similar? I.e. build data for the given interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also looking for something like this and the closest I have been able to find is this [babel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-flow-to-gen). I haven't tried it yet, but the biggest problem is that is 2 years old, so it probably does not support most of the newest flow capabilities. 
Let us know if you find something else =D